# I cant't connect appium-server desktop and appium inspector with my smartphone while i can see my device is well connected in my terminal on windows

Tags: appium-android

I just used Appium-desktop to see logs during the connection with my smartphone and Appium-inspector to inspect the DOM too, I'm new in this exercise and I search a lot without any result for the moment. I can see my smartphone is well connected and the server seems to work.
[image]

I created a Android folder in C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Local, in it I have installed cmdline-tools, platform-tools and run the command :
sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3" to install others packages in the Android folder
My environment:

```
OS : Windows 10  
Appium version : 1.22.0  
Node : v14.17.6  
Npm : 6.14.15  
Sdkmanager : 4.0.1
```

I show you in pictures the state of Appium-desktop at the starting and during the processus
[image]

My host is 0.0.0.0, port: 4723
[image]

```
Disared capabilities: platformName: Android  
                      deviceName: HUAWEI VNS-L31  
                      udid: FUH7N16607025752  
                      plateformVersion: 7.0
```

And unfortunately it doesn't work when I start session
[image]
[image]

I have this error message:

```
"Error
Failed to create session. The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource"
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea please?

Answer (score 43):

I had the same problem.
Try the following:

1. Go to Appium Server GUI -> Advanced
   Server address: localhost
   Port: 4723
   Allow CORP: yes
2. Go to Appium Inspector
   Remote host: localhost
   Port: 4723
   Path: /wd/hub
3. Allow Unauthorized Certificates
4. Select your capabilities
5. Start server

Comment: Thankyou Juna, this really helped me out in setting up the app.

Comment: This really helped. After 1 hour of checking all the combination of configurations.

Answer (score 19):

Just write in remote path:

```
/wd/hub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding /wd/hub worked for me. Perfect

Comment: Worked. Thanks. Better than official docs

Answer (score 4):

[image: Adding /wd/hub worked charm i also used appium 1.22.0]

Adding /wd/hub worked charm i also used appium 1.22.0

Comment: man you're a legend

Comment: I tried adding that to Remote Path, but the same error "Type check for option "path" failed: The option "path" needs to start with a "/" " keeps displaying. My appium server is v1.22.3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I have set the remote path in appium inspector it got resolved

To set the remote path follow below steps

- Open Appium inspector
- Under appium server, set the Remote Port : 4723 and Remote path : /wd/hub

once it's done, re-start the appium inspector, this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Appium Server: allow cors
[image]

Appium inspector: desired capabilities as per your app
[image]