# Error-Type check for option "path" failed: The option "path" needs to start with a "/"

Tags: path, appium, inspector

While starting the session in Appium Inspector, I am getting the following error:

> Error-Type check for option "path" failed: The option "path" needs to start with a "/"

as shown in the link below. Can anyone guide me for the same?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can try [the linked config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69374297/i-cantt-connect-appium-server-desktop-and-appium-inspector-with-my-smartphone-w) and start session

Answer (score -1):

Try remote path "127.0.0.1" instead of "0.0.0.0" and it should work. I was getting same error. I chage my remote path and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Start your remote Path with `/`
`/wd/hub` should do the trick.

Your remote port should also be 4723 by default

Before clicking "start session" ensure you run command `appium` in the shell. This would start your server.